# Error 400 al querer consumir Api rest con SpringBoot desde Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Buenas gracias por leer mi pregunta, resulta que estoy haciendo mi primer App con fron y backend por separado (Angular y Spring Boot), ya realice crud en otros modulos pero en este solo he listado los productos y al quererlos guardar me marca error 400, lei que segun este error se debe a que la data enviada es erronia, desde postman guarda correctamente el objeto pero desde el front no y segun yo es la misma data :V ...

Este es mi Json que se guarda sin problemas en la bd

```
{
  "idProducto":0, 
  "categoria": {
      "idCategoria": 2,
      "categoria": "Red Force"
  },
  "seVendePor": "Bulto",
  "nombreP": "Semillas Mixtas 22.7 Kg",
  "pCompra": 917.0,
  "pVenta": 1050.0,
  "iva": 0.16,
  "stock": 4.0,
  "codBarras": "sm"
```

}

Este es mi metodo TS

```
  guardar(){
    
      this.producto.push(
          {
            idProducto:0,
            categoria: {
                idCategoria: 2,
                categoria: "Red Force"
            },
            seVendePor: "Bulto",
            nombreP: "Inicio 22.7 Kg",
            pCompra: 917.0,
            pVenta: 1050.0,
            iva: 0.16,
            stock: 4.0,
            codBarras: "sm"
        }
        );
    
       if(this.formularioProductos.invalid){
          this.formularioProductos.markAllAsTouched();
          return;
        };
        this.cargando = true;
        this.serviceProduct.agregarProducto(this.producto).subscribe({
          next:() =>{
           this.reportarCierre();
            this.cargando = false;
          },
          error:(err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
            alert(err.message); 
            this.cargando = false;
          }
        });    
        this.limpiar();
      }
```

Este es mi servicio

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Producto } from '../Productos/interfaceProducto.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductoService {

  URL = "http://localhost:8090/productos";
  URLProductoXnombre = "http://localhost:8090/productos/consulXnombre"
  URLProductoXcategoria = "http://localhost:8090/productos/consulXcategoria"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 agregarProducto(p: Producto[]){
    return this.http.post<Producto[]>(this.URL,p);
 } 

 listarProducto(){
  return this.http.get<Producto[]>(this.URL);
}

listarProductoXcodB(codBarras:string){
  return this.http.get<Producto[]>(`${this.URL}/${codBarras}`);
}

listarProductoXnombre(nombreP:string){
  return this.http.get<Producto[]>(`${this.URLProductoXnombre}/${nombreP}`);
}

listarProductoXcategoria(idCategoria: number){
  return this.http.get<Producto[]>(`${this.URLProductoXcategoria}/${idCategoria}`);
}

eliminarProducto(id: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.delete(`${this.URL}/${id}`);
} 

private _listners = new Subject<any>();
listen(): Observable<any>{
  return this._listners.asObservable();
}

filter(filterBy: string){
  this._listners.next(filterBy);
}
}
```

En otros modulos llegue a darme cuenta que el error de la conexion se debia a mayusculas u orden en el que enviaba la info pero aqui si me lista los productos pero por si las dudas aqui esta mi interface

Interface

```
import { Categoria } from "../Categorias/interfaceCategoria.component";

export interface Producto{
  idProducto:number;
  categoria:Categoria;
  seVendePor:string;
  nombreP:string;
  pCompra:number;
  pVenta:number;
  iva:number,
  stock:number;
  codBarras:string;
}
```

Por si a alguien le sirve, lo resolvi de esta manera, para enviar dos obejetos anidados con formularios reactivos use un formGroup dentro de otro formGroup y en el mat-select del html no use formControlName si no [(value)]=" variable en el TS " que devuelve el index seleccionado, luego cree una instancia del objeto anidado y remplace el valor nulo del formGrup principal por el index selecionado.

Mi TS

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Categoria } from 'src/app/Categorias/interfaceCategoria.component';
import { Proveedor } from 'src/app/Proveedores/interfaceProveedor.component';
import { categoriaService } from 'src/app/Services/categoria.service';
import { ProductoService } from 'src/app/Services/producto.service';
import { ProveedorService } from 'src/app/Services/proveedor.service';
import { Producto } from '../../interfaceProducto.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-product',
  templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.css']
})
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {

  cargando = false;
  categorias: Categoria[] = [];
  idCategoria:number = 0;
  proveedores: Proveedor[] = [];
  producto: Producto[] = [];
  seVendePor: String[] = ['Kilo', 'Gramo', 'Bulto', 'Unidad'];

  formularioProductos: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
   categoria: this.fb.group(
     {
        idCategoria: [''],
        categoria: ['']
     }
   ),
     seVendePor: ['', [Validators.required]],
     nombreP: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)]],
     pCompra: ['', [Validators.required]],
     pVenta: ['', [Validators.required]],
     iva: ['', [Validators.required]],
     stock: ['', [Validators.required]],
     codBarras: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private serviceCate: categoriaService,
    private serviceprovee: ProveedorService,
    private serviceProduct: ProductoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategorias();
    this.getProveedores();
  }

  getCategorias() {
    this.cargando = true;
    this.serviceCate.listarCategorias().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        this.categorias = res;
        this.cargando = false;
      },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(err.message);
        this.cargando = false;
      }
    })
  }

  getProveedores() {
    this.cargando = true;
    this.serviceprovee.listarProveedor().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        this.proveedores = res;
        this.cargando = false;
      },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(err.message);
        this.cargando = false;
      }
    })
  }

  limpiar(): void {
    this.formularioProductos.reset();
  }

  reportarCierre() {
    this.serviceProduct.filter('dialog cerrado');
  }


  guardar() {

    if (this.formularioProductos.invalid) {
      this.formularioProductos.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    };
    this.cargando = true;

    let c:Categoria = {
      idCategoria: this.idCategoria,
      categoria: ""
    }
    
    this.formularioProductos.get('categoria')?.patchValue(c);
        
    this.serviceProduct.agregarProducto(this.formularioProductos.value).subscribe({
      next:() =>{
       this.reportarCierre();
        this.cargando = false;
      },
      error:(err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
        alert(err.message); 
        this.cargando = false;
      }
    });    
    this.limpiar();
  } 

}
```

Mi HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="guardar()" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="formularioProductos">
                        <table style="margin-left: 70px;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="ancho">
                                            <mat-label>Categoria</mat-label>
                                            <mat-select [(value)]="idCategoria">
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let categoria of categorias"
                                                    [value]="categoria.idCategoria">
                                                    {{categoria.categoria}}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="ancho">
                                            <mat-label>Proveedor</mat-label>
                                            <mat-select>
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let proveedor of proveedores"
                                                    [value]="proveedor.idProveedor">
                                                    {{proveedor.nombre}}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>¿ Como se vende ?</mat-label>
                                            <mat-select formControlName="seVendePor">
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let s of seVendePor" [value]="s">{{s}}</mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="nombreP">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Codigo de barras</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="codBarras">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Precio de compra</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="pCompra">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Precio de venta</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="pVenta">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Iva</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="iva">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-label>Stock</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput apaereci formControlName="stock">
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <button mat-mini-fab color="accent"
                                                style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 15px;" (click)="limpiar()">
                                                <mat-icon>cleaning_services</mat-icon>
                                            </button>
                                            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" style="margin-right: 15px;"
                                                (click)="limpiar()" routerLink="/productos/listado">
                                                <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                                            </button>
                                            <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" type="submit"
                                                style="margin-right: 15px;" [disabled]="formularioProductos.invalid">
                                                <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </form>
```